# How to copy and paste a file through the command-line?

Tags: command-line, cp

I want to copy and paste a file to `/usr` folder but I guess I need root access to do so so I need to learn how to copy and paste a file from one location to another through the terminal.

Comment: Copy and Paste is not the same as copying files.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:
For a file: `sudo cp /path/to/file /path/to/destination-folder/`
For a folder: `sudo cp -R /path/to/folder /path to destination-folder`